# Explaining why results from a sample may be accurate for community (+/-)

Tags: confidence-interval, interpretation, survey-sampling

This is less a statistics question and more a how to share statistics with the public question. I am presenting results of a community health survey at a series of community meetings in an area where the average educational attainment is about 10th grade. At my last meeting, someone in the audience said, "Hang on! Only 50 people said that. 1000 people live here. How can you say that what they said is what everyone would say?"

I tried explaining why sampling works and confidence intervals in very simple terms, but my version of simple is not simple enough and I could not figure out a way to do it without saying "probability" or "statistically" and ended up saying, "It is that way because that is the way it is?" (yeah I know....I shouldn't be let out in public). Can anyone think of a way to explain this in 3-7 sentences using language at about a 4th grade literacy level?